# How to right align text in a Text Box using skin file?

Tags: html, text, textbox, text-alignment, skin

I want to to right align text in a `TextBox` in ASP.NET WebSite using a *.skin file* (I cannot use a *.css file*)

I've already tried:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" SkinId="aa" style="text-align:right" ></asp:TextBox>
```

and

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" SkinId="aa" text-align ="right"></asp:TextBox>
```

Any help is appreciated.

edit:
I just saw this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign(v=vs.110).aspx

How could this property by invoked from a skin file?

thanks n advance

Answer (score 0):

Try float:right CSS property in your code.

Comment: i cannot use a _css_ file.. have to use _skin_ file

Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" SkinId="aa" float="right" ></asp:TextBox>

this doesn't work as well..

Comment: Can you not cascade style-sheets to asp.net page?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPn9RuwFNfA

Comment: i know how to but my senior has asked me not to.. i want to achieve the same result through a _skin_ file

Comment: Try this line:
<asp:TextBox runat="server" SkinId="aa"  textalign ="right"></asp:TextBox>